# Inserir datas no banco de dados?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como faço para inserir o máximo de dias de um mês via insert no codeigniter?
Ex:

```
data       |  campo2    camp3
01/01/2014 |
02/01/2014 |
03/01/2014 |
    .      |
    .      |
    .      |
31/01/2014 |
```

Comment: Você quer o último dia do mês ?

Comment: vc quer inserir no banco por ex: do dia primeiro até o último que pode ser 28, 29, 30 e 31. isso?

Comment: Exatamente isso!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível gerar essas datas a partir do seguinte loop.

Adapte o loop de acordo com o método de inserção do codeigniter (Não me lembro como é a sintaxe do Active Record dele)

```
<?php 

$dataAtual = new DateTime();

// Imprime a data atual - Teste
echo $dataAtual->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

// 't' retorna o último dia do mês de $dataAtual 
$ultimoDiaDoMes = $dataAtual->format('t');

for ($dia = 1; $dia <= $ultimoDiaDoMes; $dia++){
    $diaLoop = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dataAtual->format('Y-m-') . $dia);

    // Aqui você insere o método para inserir no banco

    // Imprime a data do loop - Teste
    echo $diaLoop->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Terá como resultado:

> ```
> 2014-06-09
>
> 2014-06-01
> 2014-06-02
> 2014-06-03
> 2014-06-04
> 2014-06-05
> 2014-06-06
> ...
> 2014-06-28
> 2014-06-29
> 2014-06-30
> ```

Comment: Valeu cara era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!